# Couchbase strange view behavior with keys with zero

Tags: couchbase

I hava a database, that contains chat messages between users (1 message copy per user: 1 message for sender and one for recepient). Running Couchbase server 2.0 cluster with 2 machines (1 linux and 1 windows).

I use such map function to retreive messages betwen users:

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.type == "msg"){
    emit([doc.OwnerId, doc.SndrId, doc.Date], {"Date":doc.Date, "OwnerId":doc.OwnerId, "RcptId":doc.RcptId, "SndrId":doc.SndrId, "Text":doc.Text, "Unread":doc.Unread, "id": doc.id, "type":doc.type});
    emit([doc.OwnerId, doc.RcptId, doc.Date], {"Date":doc.Date, "OwnerId":doc.OwnerId, "RcptId":doc.RcptId, "SndrId":doc.SndrId, "Text":doc.Text, "Unread":doc.Unread, "id": doc.id, "type":doc.type});
  }
}
```

So if I try to receive some messages (ordered decending by date) from the beggining I used such startkey & endkey:

```
startkey=[1,2,{}]
endkey=[1,2,0]
```

But in this way I get not all messages. To get all messages I need to use

```
startkey=[1,2,{}]
endkey=[1,2]
```

Here is an example. For key with zero:

```
{"total_rows":1106,"rows":[
{"id":"msg_8aaca454-5580-4e49-a081-918d8eaba9d6","key":[8,75,1342200837278],"value":{"Date":1342200837278,"OwnerId":8,"RcptId":8,"SndrId":75,"Text":"02","Unread":false,"id":"8aaca454-5580-4e49-a081-918d8eaba9d6","type":"msg"}},
{"id":"msg_49417551-bdc9-477b-b8c2-1f36051bb930","key":[8,75,1342199880920],"value":{"Date":1342199880920,"OwnerId":8,"RcptId":75,"SndrId":8,"Text":"4","Unread":false,"id":"49417551-bdc9-477b-b8c2-1f36051bb930","type":"msg"}},
{"id":"msg_2724f077-1e76-4fbc-9a4b-f34cb71e2db0","key":[8,75,1342108023448],"value":{"Date":1342108023448,"OwnerId":8,"RcptId":75,"SndrId":8,"Text":"55","Unread":false,"id":"2724f077-1e76-4fbc-9a4b-f34cb71e2db0","type":"msg"}},
{"id":"msg_9cc91327-4ba3-45b5-ab64-f2ca63510e8d","key":[8,75,1341413650113],"value":{"Date":1341413650113,"OwnerId":8,"RcptId":75,"SndrId":8,"Text":"3","Unread":false,"id":"9cc91327-4ba3-45b5-ab64-f2ca63510e8d","type":"msg"}},
{"id":"msg_9a386663-8a2b-42d9-ae30-0634a98fe574","key":[8,75,1341413648335],"value":{"Date":1341413648335,"OwnerId":8,"RcptId":75,"SndrId":8,"Text":"1","Unread":false,"id":"9a386663-8a2b-42d9-ae30-0634a98fe574","type":"msg"}}
]
}
```

With keys without zero:

```
{"total_rows":1106,"rows":[
{"id":"msg_dc4b7758-1f0e-491c-a80d-bf3124dc0ad7","key":[8,75,1342200856186],"value":{"Date":1342200856186,"OwnerId":8,"RcptId":8,"SndrId":75,"Text":"03","Unread":false,"id":"dc4b7758-1f0e-491c-a80d-bf3124dc0ad7","type":"msg"}},
{"id":"msg_8aaca454-5580-4e49-a081-918d8eaba9d6","key":[8,75,1342200837278],"value":{"Date":1342200837278,"OwnerId":8,"RcptId":8,"SndrId":75,"Text":"02","Unread":false,"id":"8aaca454-5580-4e49-a081-918d8eaba9d6","type":"msg"}},
{"id":"msg_b2fe9ca0-aa28-41a6-ab3c-09ece6a5e14a","key":[8,75,1342200787811],"value":{"Date":1342200787811,"OwnerId":8,"RcptId":8,"SndrId":75,"Text":"01","Unread":true,"id":"b2fe9ca0-aa28-41a6-ab3c-09ece6a5e14a","type":"msg"}},
{"id":"msg_49417551-bdc9-477b-b8c2-1f36051bb930","key":[8,75,1342199880920],"value":{"Date":1342199880920,"OwnerId":8,"RcptId":75,"SndrId":8,"Text":"4","Unread":false,"id":"49417551-bdc9-477b-b8c2-1f36051bb930","type":"msg"}},
{"id":"msg_0d7dc822-b76c-42f9-87ba-3dc486100526","key":[8,75,1342180778835],"value":{"Date":1342180778835,"OwnerId":8,"RcptId":75,"SndrId":8,"Text":"Gcgjvv6gvvbnbvvbh B2B bb cb B2B","Unread":false,"id":"0d7dc822-b76c-42f9-87ba-3dc486100526","type":"msg"}},
{"id":"msg_6b26a65f-68e1-4728-87f1-59ea5e0f0c5d","key":[8,75,1342114611144],"value":{"Date":1342114611144,"OwnerId":8,"RcptId":75,"SndrId":8,"Text":"546546546546546546546546546546","Unread":false,"id":"6b26a65f-68e1-4728-87f1-59ea5e0f0c5d","type":"msg"}},
{"id":"msg_f89b09ac-ccf1-4958-85c0-259b0b68752b","key":[8,75,1342108583566],"value":{"Date":1342108583566,"OwnerId":8,"RcptId":75,"SndrId":8,"Text":"123","Unread":false,"id":"f89b09ac-ccf1-4958-85c0-259b0b68752b","type":"msg"}},
{"id":"msg_2724f077-1e76-4fbc-9a4b-f34cb71e2db0","key":[8,75,1342108023448],"value":{"Date":1342108023448,"OwnerId":8,"RcptId":75,"SndrId":8,"Text":"55","Unread":false,"id":"2724f077-1e76-4fbc-9a4b-f34cb71e2db0","type":"msg"}},
{"id":"msg_9cc91327-4ba3-45b5-ab64-f2ca63510e8d","key":[8,75,1341413650113],"value":{"Date":1341413650113,"OwnerId":8,"RcptId":75,"SndrId":8,"Text":"3","Unread":false,"id":"9cc91327-4ba3-45b5-ab64-f2ca63510e8d","type":"msg"}},
{"id":"msg_847b2901-95e3-49b9-8756-e495872558a8","key":[8,75,1341413649161],"value":{"Date":1341413649161,"OwnerId":8,"RcptId":75,"SndrId":8,"Text":"2","Unread":false,"id":"847b2901-95e3-49b9-8756-e495872558a8","type":"msg"}}
]
}
```

Can anyone explain why it not binds all messages in first case?

Comment: Unless some of your dates are `null` or less than 0 then that makes no sense to me either.

Comment: There are no null or less then 0 dates.

Comment: All dates are stored as longints in milliseconds from 1/1/1970. Later I can provide all docs stored in base, if someone needs them. Maybe even couchbase server with that base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Filipe Manana from couchbase team, who answered this question.
This issue is caused by Erlang OTP R14B03 (and all prior versions) on 64 bits platforms.

Here is Filipe's commit that fixes this bug https://github.com/erlang/otp/commit/03d8c2877342d5ed57596330a61ec0374092f136

For more details see http://www.couchbase.com/forums/thread/couchbase-view-not-rerurning-all-values

Answer (score -1):

NB CouchDB and CouchBase are as similar as Membase and MySQL = products that start with the same prefix. Best not to get them confused!

It might be related to whether sorting is done via ASCII (what you are expecting) vs via unicode collation. Some more information here http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_collation but that applies to CouchDB, not CouchBase. Maybe that helps?

Comment: All values stored in utf-8. Also couchbase 2.0 uses couchdb to store documents, so theirs behavior can be very similar.